# Two Service Accounts In Same Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have two service-accounts for GCP and would like to use them for authentication in same project that I am working on. Both are required to access different storage services. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you need to manage this through fine-grained access control at object level

Comment: Edit your question to clearly state what your problem/goal is. You can have multiple service accounts, but how to use them depends on which services you are using. Details matter to getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only user-managed service accounts can be attached to an instance, and an instance can have only one attached service account. You can change the service account that is attached to an instance at creation time or later on
. to read more about service account you can refer to this
[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#:%7E:text=Only%20user%2Dmanaged%20service%20accounts,creation%20time%20or%20later%20on.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for GCP projects is yes, you can use two [user-managed](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed) service accounts on the same [project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#locations), but for the particular case of Google Cloud Storage, you must use [Service agents](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects#service-accounts).

Please read this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/org-policy-constraints) to be aware of the Organization policy constraints for Cloud Storage.

Merely as an example, if you want to let your application's service account access objects in a Cloud Storage bucket, you can grant the service account the Storage Object Viewer role `roles/storage.objectViewer` on the bucket. You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-access-service-accounts) to manage the access to service accounts.